# Regular Expression to find a pattern and replace just part of it

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to know how can I use RegEx to find a pattern and replace just a part of it in JavaScript.

Let's say, for example, I want to replace some patterns like this `-foo` but just if it has a `-` after it, like `-foo-` but replace just the `-foo`.

Can someone please explain in details the RegEx construction to achieve it?

I did not find a detailed explanation of it here, just codes with a minimum explanation.

Comment: If you want to turn `-foo` into `-bar` then you don't leave the hyphen and replace `foo`.  You just replace the whole thing.  I think you're overcomplicating this.

Comment: Actually, I need to replace `-foo-`, but I can have another `-foo-` after it, like: `-foo-foo-` so I need to just replace `-foo` so the other one gets replaced as well. And I need to check if there is a `-` after it, because I can have a word that begins with `foo`. And I'm replacing it for a `,`.

Comment: And I have a lot of patterns to evaluate, not just `foo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a positive look-ahead `(?=-)` that will check the existence of `-` after `-foo` but will not *consume* it:

```js
var s = "-foo- -foo";
alert(s.replace(/-foo(?=-)/g, 'REPLACED'));
```

You can read more about look-aheads (and look-behinds, though they are not supported by the JS regex engine) at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

The main idea is that the text is checked for presence or absence of some patterns defined in the look-around, and based on that either allow or fail the match. They can actually be used efficiently together with anchors, but this is not the case here.

> Lookahead and lookbehind, collectively called "lookaround", are zero-length assertions... lookaround actually matches characters, but then gives up the match, returning only the result: match or no match... They do not consume characters in the string, but only assert whether a match is possible or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked. I was not expecting something simple like that. I was searching and bumped into groups or something like that,  that I did not really understood and found that really complex, that's why I asked for a detailed explanation. But your answer was WAY better. Thanks mate.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please leave a comment with your reasoning. Otherwise, downvoting does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

As the first poster said, you need to make use of a lookahead (?=) to check for an additional character(s). In this situation, the character you need to look for is -, therefore your pattern would make use of a lookahead followed by - ie(?=-).